# Unable to get my M117B temperature sensor by Mysentech thru I2C having this error: `Sending command error, slave doesn't ACK the transfer`

Tags: sensors, esp32, i2c

I am pulling my hair for days on this.

I have a M117 temperature sensor plugged at address 0x45 in my I2C bus on my ESP32-based custom PCB.

While scanning, I see that it is there at 45.

I initially wrote enhanced my Arduino code to support this new sensor, without success. I decided to rewrite at ESP32 level using `driver/i2c.h`.
As a result, I get the error `Sending command error, slave doesn't ACK the transfer` at the line `i2c_master_cmd_begin()`.

What's wrong with my code?

My code is as follows:

```cpp
#include <driver/i2c.h>

// GPIO number used for I2C master clock
#define I2C_MASTER_SCL_IO           GPIO_NUM_22                 
// GPIO number used for I2C master data  
#define I2C_MASTER_SDA_IO           GPIO_NUM_21                 
#define I2C_MASTER_NUM              (i2c_port_t)0              /* I2C master i2c port number, the number of i2c peripheral interfaces available will depend on the chip */
#define I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ          100000                     /* I2C master clock frequency */
#define I2C_MASTER_TX_BUF_DISABLE   0                          /* I2C master doesn't need buffer */
#define I2C_MASTER_RX_BUF_DISABLE   0                          /* I2C master doesn't need buffer */
#define I2C_MASTER_TIMEOUT_MS       1000
#define SENSOR_ADDR                 0x45        /* Slave address of the Temp sensor */

// Register to read temperature  from M117B Mysentech
#define REGISTER0 0xCC
#define REGISTER1 0x44

/**
 *  i2c master initialization
 */
static esp_err_t i2cMasterInit() {
    i2c_config_t conf = {
        .mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER,
        .sda_io_num = I2C_MASTER_SDA_IO,
        .sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
        .scl_io_num = I2C_MASTER_SCL_IO,
        .scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
        {{.clk_speed = I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ}}
    };

    esp_err_t r = ESP_OK;
    r |= i2c_param_config(I2C_MASTER_NUM, &conf); // config I2C
    r |= i2c_driver_install(I2C_MASTER_NUM, conf.mode, I2C_MASTER_RX_BUF_DISABLE, I2C_MASTER_TX_BUF_DISABLE, 0); // Intall I2C
    
    if (r) thermometer.error("i2cMasterInit() result to %d", r); else thermometer.success("i2cMasterInit()");

    return r;
}

/**
 Reads the M117 temperature
*/
static esp_err_t m117ReadTemp(uint8_t *raw, size_t len) {
    i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
    esp_err_t r = ESP_OK;
    
    // == Create the I2C command
    // = Start write to register
    r |= i2c_master_start(cmd); logErrorIfAny("m117ReadTemp()|i2c_master_start()", r);     
    r |= i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, SENSOR_ADDR << 1 | I2C_MASTER_WRITE, true);
    r |= i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, REGISTER0, true); logErrorIfAny("m117ReadTemp()|i2c_master_write_byte()", r); 
    r |= i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, REGISTER1, true); logErrorIfAny("m117ReadTemp()|i2c_master_write_byte()", r); 
    
    // = Start read from register
    r |= i2c_master_start(cmd); logErrorIfAny("m117ReadTemp()|i2c_master_start()", r); 
    r |= i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, SENSOR_ADDR << 1 | I2C_MASTER_READ, true);
    r |= i2c_master_read(cmd, raw, len, I2C_MASTER_LAST_NACK); logErrorIfAny("m117ReadTemp()|i2c_master_read()", r); 
    
    // = Stop
    r |= i2c_master_stop(cmd); logErrorIfAny("m117ReadTemp()|i2c_master_stop()", r); 

    // == Send the command
    r |= i2c_master_cmd_begin(I2C_MASTER_NUM, cmd, I2C_MASTER_TIMEOUT_MS / portTICK_RATE_MS); logErrorIfAny("m117ReadTemp()|i2c_master_cmd_begin()", r); 
    
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);

    logErrorIfAny("m117ReadTemp():", r);
    return r;
}
```

*[UPDATE]*

I thought I had found the issue, because I wrote 2 successive bytes, each requiring ACK:

```cpp
    r |= i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, REGISTER0, true); 
    r |= i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, REGISTER1, true);
```

So I replaced by one write, as follows:

```cpp
    const uint8_t REGISTER[] = {REGISTER0, REGISTER1};
    r |= i2c_master_write(handle, (byte*)&REGISTER, sizeof REGISTER, true);
```

So that the ACK is issued only once.
But I still get the same error.

Btw, I aded my I2C initialising code above in the first block of code, just in case.

*[UPDATE 2]*

My current code is as follows:

```cpp
/// Reads the M117 temperature
static float m117ReadTemp(bool &ready) {
    ready = false;
    esp_err_t r = ESP_OK;
    float temperature = 0;

    i2c_cmd_handle_t handle = i2c_cmd_link_create();

    
    uint8_t REGISTER[] = {REGISTER0, REGISTER1};

    // == Create the I2C command
    // = Start write to register
    r |= i2c_master_start(handle);     
    r |= i2c_master_write_byte(handle, SENSOR_ADDR << 1 | I2C_MASTER_WRITE, true);
    r |= i2c_master_write(handle, REGISTER, sizeof REGISTER, true);  

    // = Stop
    r |= i2c_master_stop(handle);  
    
    delay(15);  // Makes no difference


    uint8_t data[2] = {0, 0};

    // = Start read from register
    r |= i2c_master_start(handle); 
    r |= i2c_master_write_byte(handle, SENSOR_ADDR << 1 | I2C_MASTER_READ, true);
    r |= i2c_master_read(handle, data, sizeof data, I2C_MASTER_LAST_NACK); 

    // = Stop
    r |= i2c_master_stop(handle); 


    delay(15); // Makes no difference

    // == Send the command
    r |= i2c_master_cmd_begin(I2C_MASTER_NUM, handle, I2C_MASTER_TIMEOUT_MS / portTICK_RATE_MS); 


    // ====> THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR POPS FROM <===
    logErrorIfAny("m117ReadTemp()|i2c_master_cmd_begin()", r); 
    

    // == Clean up
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(handle);

    // blah blah
}
```

*[UPDATE Sept 30th 2022]*

I found out the code is working if I iterate quite rapidly over time when asking for temperatures.
But If I introduced a delay of 10 seconds, for instance, I got the first one ok, and the next ones gives me the error.

Comment: Does it work with a non-custom ESP32 board?

Comment: The hardware team says it works.

Comment: Did you read the [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2108251830_Mysentech-M117_C2843548.pdf), in particularly understand the section 11.8? The sensor will go into clock stretching once the ConvertTemperature command is received. The duration of the clock stretching depend on the resolution you set on Configuration Register but it could be as long as 10.5ms (see Table 9.2-2) + 1ms. So you need to add `r |= i2c_master_stop(cmd);` and add a `delay(12)` before you start reading the temperature reading.

Comment: Yeah, I did. But it makes no difference. Would you mind we enter in a chat?